# Does AWS CloudFront support country code top level domains not available for registration?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

There are some [ccTLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) that I am interested in that are not available for registration through AWS Route 53, according to [their list](https://d32ze2gidvkk54.cloudfront.net/Amazon_Route_53_Domain_Registration_Pricing_20140731.pdf). Having registered such a domain with another registrar, and being able to change the name servers, can I still use CloudFront as a CDN for a website?

Looked at [Making Route 53 the DNS service for a domain that's in use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) but could not see a specific answer to this. Also, their CDN [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deliver-content-faster/) skips the topic of domains:

> CloudFront will automatically assign you a domain name when you create
> a web distribution (for example,
> http://abcdefghi888.cloudfront.net/filename.jpg). You can also specify
> your own domain name in the URLs for your objects (such as
> http://yourDomain.com/filename.jpg) once you update your DNS
> configuration to route DNS queries to your CloudFront distribution.
> For this tutorial, leave this field blank.

If they do support it, would also be great to know if:

a) This remains available in the [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing)

b) If there is any special setup for it

By the way, CloudFlare does not support ccTLDs that they cannot register, based on a [community answer](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/which-country-domains-are-supported-by-cloudflare/422148), and that's one reason I'm wondering if it's also the case with AWS CloudFront. Thank you!

Comment: Do you read that CF document correctly? They state that they don't let you *transfer* non-supported ccTLD's to them - not that you can't use non-supported TLD's with CF.

Comment: I didn't see any confirmation that they *do not* support it, I just want confirmation that they *do*, because with Cloudflare for example, it wasn't 100% clear either. If you found such confirmation or know from experience, would be glad to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: To me the CF discussion was very clear; it was about *transferring*. I can't really see *any* reason why it would not work, and the easiest way to confirm it would be to test it.

Comment: You're right, I should clarify that this is about the CDN, not switching domain registrars. I did test it on CF with an unsupported ccTLD, the UI stays stuck pending DNS verification or something like that, even though the nameservers have changed. With a ".com" domain it's very quick. I don't use CloudFront at all at the moment, and would like to avoid going through a whole setup only to find out it doesn't work either, if possible, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Probably Yes**

Tried again with Cloudflare and managed to add the ccTLD, even though it remains with another registrar. Not sure why it didn't work the other two times, third time lucky maybe. The "not supported" discussions on Cloudflare community site are probably related to domain transfer.

Since I have proven that it is possible to have a ccTLD not on their list as an "active site" on Clouflare, I conclude that it is likely possible that it will also work on CloudFront. I am no longer interested in trying it at this point.

Enabling DNSSEC through Cloudflare took a long time. It was stuck for several days on "*DNSSEC is pending while we wait for the DS to be added to your registrar. This usually takes ten minutes, but can take up to an hour*" even though I added the required DS record on the registrar. However, it was good eventually. Don't know how that would work in Cloudfront.

> *Side Note*: Leaving this open in case it is useful to others. If
> somebody can confirm this on CloudFront, I'll take it as the accepted
> answer. If on the other hand, people feel that this question has no
> value, please add a comment and I will (try to) delete this post
> entirely. Thanks.